# non explicit recursion in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I need some help with doing recursion in scheme using just the abstract list functions. As an example, how would I change this code with explicit recursion so that it wouldn't have the function name in the body:

```
(define (make_unique_list lst) 
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(member? (first lst) (rest lst)) (make_unique_list (rest lst))]
    [else (cons (first lst) (make_unique_list (rest lst)))]))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R6RS Scheme:

```
(import (rnrs) (rnrs lists))

(define (make-unique-list lst)
  (reverse
   (fold-left
    (lambda (r e) (if (member e r) r (cons e r)))
    '()
    lst)))

(display (make-unique-list '(1 2 3 4 3 5 6 3 2 1 7)))
=> {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}
```

In Racket:

```
(define (make-unique-list lst)
  (reverse
   (foldl
    (lambda (e r) (if (member e r) r (cons e r)))
    '()
    lst)))
```

or

```
(define (make-unique-list lst)
  (reverse
   (for/fold ((r '())) ((e (in-list lst)))
     (if (member e r) r (cons e r)))))
```

Note that in the first 2 examples I use `reverse` and `foldl` / `fold-left`, not `foldr` or `fold-right` (try it for yourself to see why).

BTW, this procedure is often called `remove-duplicates` and is build-in in Racket:

```
(remove-duplicates '(1 2 3 4 3 5 6 3 2 1 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `fold` can be used. By combining the logic from the non-empty cases in the `cond` into one accumulate function, we can selectively accumulate the items in the list that we haven't seen yet.

Recall that the function given to fold has two parameters: one is the current item and the other is the current accumulated value. In this case, the current item will be of type X and the current accumulated value will be a list of X. The function needs to return a list of X.

If you need to preserve the order of the input list, be judicious in selecting between `fold-right` and `fold-left` or the equivalents in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to express anonymous, recursive functions in Scheme using the so-called [Y combinator](http://www.ece.uc.edu/~franco/C511/html/Scheme/ycomb.html). I haven't used it myself, but that's mainly because it's kind of tricky to understand. It's useful though.

see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator

Comment: "non explicit" i.e. implicit recursion usually means fold. Recursion through **Y** is still a recursion, there's still a function call there, e.g. `Y (λ fact.λ n.n < 2 ? 1 ; n*fact(n-1))`. Though anonymous, it's still a recursion. :)

Comment: @WillNess Your're right - I might have misinterpreted the question. Still, using Y-comb. you don't explicitly use any function *name*, which was mentioned in the question.

Comment: We use `fact`... it's just that that function `fact` is created on the spot for us, by Y. Not some global function; still, a function. :)

Comment: I have to agree with Herman. The Y combinator is still some kind of implicit recursion. The Y combinator sounds like a higher order function just like fold.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix `foldNat (λ n.λ r.n*r) 1`: no function-calling in sight.